# Can I use reduce to turn an array into an array of objects with custom keys and also counting duplicate values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-manipulation

In my current code I have an array of names which get turned into an object with reduce(), and any duplicate names will increment a count value.

Initial array (nameArray):

```
["Name1","Name2","Name2","Name2","Name3","Name4","Name5"]
```

Reduce code:

```
    const nameCount = nameArray.reduce((a, b) => {
        a[b] = (a[b] || 0) + 1
        return a
    }, {})
```

Reduce output:

```
{"Name1":1,"Name2":3,"Name3":1,"Name4":1,"Name5":1}
```

I want to change the format of this to be like so:

```
[
{
"name": Name1,
"count": 1
},
{
"name": Name2,
"count": 3
},
{
"name": Name3,
"count": 1
}
...etc
]
```

Is this possible by using just reduce? What would be the best, most efficient way to do this?
I've tried changing my reduce code but haven't been able to get it to work, nor did my search for solutions result in anything.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create the desired array inside the `reduce` method but it's not efficient because every time you need to search by `name` in order to update the count.

One easy way could be using `Object.keys` method.

```js
var nameArray = ["Name1","Name2","Name2","Name2","Name3","Name4","Name5"]
const nameCount = nameArray.reduce((a, b) => {
    a[b] = (a[b] || 0) + 1
    return a
}, {})
console.log(Object.keys(nameCount).map(key => ({name : key, count: nameCount[key]})));
```

Comment: The other answers are good but I chose this one due to simplicity. Can I just make sure I understand how this works (sorry, I really am a noob): Object.keys returns an array of all the keys from the object (the names), then we map it and "key" is given the value of the current item being processed, then we return an object with the values of key (the name) and nameCount[key] which for example would be nameCount[Name1] which is 1. Is that right?

Comment: @chX, yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you want only use `Array.reduce()`:

```js
const nameArray = ["Name1", "Name2", "Name2", "Name2", "Name3", "Name4", "Name5"];

const nameCount = nameArray.reduce((ac, a) => {
  const index = ac.findIndex(({ name }) => name === a); 
  if(index > -1) {
    ac[index].count++;
  } else {
    ac.push({ name: a, count: 1 });
  } 
  return ac;
}, [])

console.log(nameCount)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do it with `reduce`. For example:

```
const nameCount = nameArray.reduce((a, val) => {
  const obj = a.find(x => x.name === val);
  if (obj) {
    obj.count++;
  } else {
    a.push({name: val, count: 1});
  }
  return a
}, []);
```

What is "best" and "most efficient" is open to interpretation.

Each run of the reducer needs to check for a duplicate. This does it by iterating through the array again. So the total time complexity is `O(n^2)`. To do better, you'll need an additional data structure to store a mapping of name to index in the accumulator. Then you could get `O(n)`.